# Angular - Openlayers

Tags: angular, openlayers

I'm building map with openlayers in angular and there's a problem that controls (zoom with mouse and mouse double click, put marker) don't work and the code [is here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-b8kybu) i want to put single marker and get latitude and longitude of marked marker
I have tried ngx-openlayers and it does the same problem of controls i mention
I was wonder if there is a good map api with angular except google and openlayers tell me and a resource to it please

Comment: See https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/issues/10732  Adding `"node_modules/ol/ol.css"` to the styles section of angular.json and removing `controls: []` so the default controls are used fixes it.

Comment: It doesn't work correctly after adding bootstrap and ol.css in angular.json ... you can [edit](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-b8kybu) and save it

Comment: This is working for me https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-q3hyay

Comment: thanks for your editing ... do you suggest how to put marker and get latitude and longitude of marked marker

Comment: You can look at [https://github.com/bayramucuncu/b3-ol-map](https://github.com/bayramucuncu/b3-ol-map) for openlayers based angular application.

Answer (score 0):

If you import OL style in `styles.css` then you will solve you problem.

*style.css*

```
@import '~ol/ol.css';
```

Another way of achieving this is what @Mike suggest in the comments, adding the OL style to `styles` array in `angular.json`.

*UPDATE*

Basically, you need two things to achieve what you want:

- disable default `dblclick` zoom-in interaction of the map
- listen to map `dblclick` event

Take a look at this example I made for you,

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v6.1.1/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
    <style>
      .map {
        height: 400px;
        width: 100%;
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v6.1.1/build/ol.js"></script>
    <title>Add Markers</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h2>Add Markers</h2>
    <div class="map" id="map"></div>
    <p id="log"></p>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    const vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector();
    const vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
      source: vectorSource,
      style: new ol.style.Style({
        image: new ol.style.Circle({
          radius: 7,
          fill: new ol.style.Fill({color: 'black'}),
          stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
            color: 'white', width: 2
          })
        })
      })
    })
  const map = new ol.Map({
   target: 'map',
   layers: [
    new ol.layer.Tile({
     source: new ol.source.OSM()
    }),
        vectorLayer
   ],
   view: new ol.View({
    center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([-80, 35]),
    zoom: 12
   }),
      interactions: ol.interaction.defaults({ doubleClickZoom: false })
  });
    map.on('dblclick', function(evt) {
      const coord = map.getCoordinateFromPixel(evt.pixel);
      vectorSource.addFeature(new ol.Feature({
        geometry: new ol.geom.Point(coord)
      }));
      const coordll = ol.proj.toLonLat(coord);
      document.getElementById('log').innerHTML +=
      `Coord:${coordll[0].toFixed(2)} ${coordll[1].toFixed(2)}<br>`
      console.log(`Coord:${coordll[0].toFixed(2)} ${coordll[1].toFixed(2)}`);
    });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion it works fine... do you suggest how to put marker and get latitude and longitude of marked marker?